# Rotate external display with AppleScript in macOS 13 (Ventura)

Tags: automation, applescript, display, macos-ventura, sirishortcuts

I would like to rotate one of my 2 external displays 90 degrees (and back), using AppleScript (ultimately, as a Shortcut), on macOS 13 (Ventura)

I was able to do this on macOS 12, but things have changed:

1. New Ventura system setting names
2. Unsure how to select one of my 2 external displays
3. May need to "confirm" rotation (if system asks for it)

Thanks for any solutions

References

- Solution for previous version (macOS 12): https://stackoverflow.com/a/71732264/3217870
- Ventura setting names: https://www.macosadventures.com/2022/12/05/how-to-open-every-section-of-macos-ventura-system-settings/